# Can i set "Any" for bind param in perl (Oracle's SQL)

Tags: sql, perl, oracle, dbi

In Perl module I have code like this:

```
 ...
 my $param = 123;
 my $sql = "select id, name from obj where id = ?";
 $sth = $DBH->prepare($sql) || die $DBH->errstr;
 $sth->execute($param) || die $DBH->errstr;
 ...
```

whern param has value all is well, but in this module there are conditions when you need to select all rows from table (in my code $param = undef)

Does anyone know how to do this without changing the query?

thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually prefer to solution provided by bohica, but Oracle can do some strange optimizations, and playing a bit with the query can for some queries get much better performance, or much worse. (Always benchmark any solution)

```
select * from cust where cust_no = nvl(?, cust_no);
```

This will match cust_no = ? when the bind variable is set and cust_no = cust_no when the bind variable is null. Oracle does optimize cust_no = cust_no out usually and just returns all rows.

Comment: good point, I was providing a generic solution rather than an Oracle specific one.

Answer (score 2):

It cannot be done without changing the query as you cannot compare something with NULL using '=' and undef is NULL; you need to use 'is null' or 'is not null'. Search for "NULL values" in [DBI](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI) and it will explain.

**Revision after comments:**

If I understand the problem correctly now you may want to select all rows or specific rows based on whether a Perl scalar is undef or not. A solution would be:

```
my $sql = q/select something from table where ? is null or column = ?/;
$s->prepare($sql);
# here $param is undef for all rows and !undef for specific rows
$s->execute($param, $param);
```

Comment: yes, null value is cool, but my big problem - how to set some like " id LIKE '%'"  params in querry for any datatype columns

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. How could you do that with parameters or without changing the SQL. Perhaps a specific example of what you do want to do would help.

Comment: yes. u undertand me right. now i do so : if ($param != undef) { $where = " where  id = $param "};  my $sql = "select id, name from obj $where;$sth = $DBH->prepare($sql); $sth->execute(). But it's not right way besause this way scores oracle's cache, and i don't know how do it right :-(